# Expecting value on the json.loads

Tags: python, json, django

in my app am calling a php script which will return a json encoded string

```
    output = str(subprocess.check_output(["php","-f" ,  "../connector/somefile.php" ,"code_string:"+code_string]));
    print(output)
```

here is my  print(output)

```
b'{"success":"1","code":"pewcndIiD8WcB5MdH+8JOAVJ03xlt92sIUYgs2m2tIGtLohnDHjBP8s8x9\\/YroJnyrCLcyN6Brwicn9\\/DS4j9kH8a6gcOKFS1bpmvdKxJSrmgT0aO
z0u16npbt1ldklXx16WEybEN4gKG0DI="}'
```

when i try to decode it into a dictionary

```
 dic = json.loads(output)
```

i get

```
ValueError at /myapp/

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

whats wrong with this line ? isn't it a valid json ? i pretty sure im generating valid json object in the php file but i'm not sure what the extra `b` is in the begining of json string in the python side

Comment: Your output variable has probably been overwritten somewhere. Are there lines of code between where `output` is generated and the `json.loads`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye no , this is my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'b` stands for byte-string, if you decode it, it should work

```
json.loads(output.decode('utf-8'))
{'code': 'pewcndIiD8WcB5MdH+8JOAVJ03xlt92sIUYgs2m2tIGtLohnDHjBP8s8x9/YroJnyrCLcyN6Brwicn9/DS4j9kH8a6gcOKFS1
bpmvdKxJSrmgT0aOz0u16npbt1ldklXx16WEybEN4gKG0DI=', 'success': '1'}
```